# Safely deleting a commit after git amend and git push --force

Tags: git, github

I am not a git expert and I am trying to save code that I am working on.
I wanted to rename the most recent commit by following the steps described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/).
Particularly, I first ran

```
git commit --amend
```

to correct misspelled commit message using a text editor locally,
then

```
git push --force
```

to update GitHub repository.
Everything went well except that I still have a (I believe, sorry for a bad terms) upstream changes labeled red in git gui:

[image]

That say

> Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index

This red labeled changes are the same as my recently amended commit. Running `git pull` just says that

> Already up to date

So, my question is how to remove those 'duplicate' changes? (node labelled red on the picture above).
I am afraid that running: `git reset --hard HEAD^` will just remove the last amended commit

Comment: Both `git gui` and `gitk` represent uncommitted work (in the index and/or in the work-tree) as a red circle that *looks like* a commit. But it's not a commit; it cannot be transferred to another Git via `git push` or `git fetch`, which transfer only commits. You can turn it *into* a commit with appropriate `git add`s followed by `git commit`, and then you can transfer it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I suspected that I can just run `git add` and then commit it, but won't I have two commits with duplicate code? The amended commit already has all the necessary changes, also I pushed it successfully. My question is how can I remove local uncommitted changes or somehow merge them to the recent successful commit

Comment: Hi. In comment form now :)
Can you try to run `git diff` and see what the actual differences between the last amended commit and the working tree (the "red commit circle" in gitk) are?

Comment: I already run `git diff`. It shows that the actual differences are exactly the same as those that were committed in the amended commit. The commit I amended is also at the top of HEAD, while local duplicate changes are at the top of Index tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by simply making changes to the file that was in upstream node (labelled red) captioned

> Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index

and committed it.

The "Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index" were overridden by my new commit